# Auto alerting on Android upon file copy to phone

Tags: images, alerts

I have an PC based app that periodically copies some images to a Samsung Note-II via USB. (The target folder etc. are all configurable)

I need the Note-II to automatically display the most recent copied image and play an audible alert tone when a file is copied onto the device. Is there any configuration in Android to let me do that? Other than the obvious way of writing a custom Android app?

Answer (score 5):

You could try with [On{x}](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.onx.app#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5vbnguYXBwIl0.) a free app by Microsoft before going for Tasker (paid) where you could do it using the "file modified" context on the directory where the images are copied.

Comment: very helpful, let me check it out....